# How would i go about getting the name of an object that's inside of an array without directly referencing the object?

Tags: javascript

This was my initial solution, but I discovered that `Object.keys` does not work with an array index.

```
let myArrayForObjects = [];

function firstFunc(){
    myArrayForObjects.push(object1, object2, object3);

}

function secondFunc(){
    for (let i = 0; i < myArrayForObjects.length; i++){
        let varName = Object.keys({myArrayForObjects[i]}[0]); 
        console.log(varName);
    }
}
```

I posted it as here and was suggested the following solution:

```
let myArrayForObjects = [];

function firstFunc(){
    myArrayForObjects.push(object1, object2, object3);
}

function secondFunc(){
    for (let i = 0; i < myArrayForObjects.length; i++){
        // Find the object in the array
        let objectIndex = myArrayForObjects.indexOf(myArrayForObjects[i]);
        // Get the object's name
        let objectName = Object.keys(myArrayForObjects)[objectIndex];
        console.log(objectName);
    }
}
```

But that logs `1`, `2` and `3` to the console. And what I want it to log is `object1`, `oject2`, and `object3`.

Is it even possible to do what I want? Or should I just add a property to the object with its name?

Comment: There is no association between the object in the array and the variable names that used to refer to the objects before they were put into the array. If you need that information, explicitly store it as a string somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the objects in an array, put them in an object like so:

```
const myObjects = { object1, object2, object3 }
```

You can now either access them by name:

```
console.log(myObjects.object1)
```

Or iterate on the objects if needed:

```
console.log(Object.values(myObjects))
```